# pass array as parameter

Tags: php, smarty

is it possible to pass array as parameter in smarty? here is my code. thanks

```
{foreach from = $diamond_all key = k item = value}
    <tr class="gradeA" id="diamond_id_">
        <td>{$value.Shape}</td>
        <td>{$value.CaratPerPrice}</td>
        <td>Add Ring</td>
        {$value.ID}">Certificate</a></td>
        <td>{$value.Weight}</td>
        <td>{$value.Cut}</td>
        <td>{$value.Color}</td>
        <td>{$value.Clarity}</td>
        <td>{$value.Price}</td>
        <td> <a class="view_details cboxElement" href="array.php?name=PASS_ARRAY">{$value.ID} View Details</a></td>
    </tr>
{/foreach}
```

EDIT
I have array like this in php format. then I'm printing this array using smarty.

```
  [0] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 30237638
        [Shape] => Round
        [Weight] => 1.000
        [Cut] => Good
        [Color] => F
        [Clarity] => VS2
        [Price] => 5282.48
        [Company] => 
        [VendorStockNumber] => 92102001
        [Symmetry] => Very Good
        [Polish] => Excellent
        [Depth] => 65.1
        [Table] => 57.00
        [MeasLength] => 6.20
        [MeasWidth] => 6.24
        [MeasDepth] => 4.05
        [GirdleSizeMin] => Slightly Thick
        [GirdleSizeMax] => Thick
        [Culet] => None
        [Fluorescence] => None
        [CaratPerPrice] => 5282.48
        [CertificateNumber] => 2131048944
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest PHP's [`http_build_query`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php). You can generate the details link in PHP and assign in Smarty (or if you'd be doing that a lot, you could write a Smarty plugin to make the call to [`http_build_query`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php). [Documentation](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.tpl))

PHP:

```
$diamond = array(
    'ID' => 30237638,
    'Shape' => 'Round',
    'Weight' => 1.000,
    'Cut' => 'Good',
    'Color' => 'F',
    'Clarity' => 'VS2',
    'Price' => 5282.48,
    'Company' => '',
    'VendorStockNumber' => 92102001,
    'Symmetry' => 'Very Good',
    'Polish' => 'Excellent',
    'Depth' => 65.1,
    'Table' => 57.00,
    'MeasLength' => 6.20,
    'MeasWidth' => 6.24,
    'MeasDepth' => 4.05,
    'GirdleSizeMin' => 'Slightly Thick',
    'GirdleSizeMax' => 'Thick',
    'Culet' => 'None',
    'Fluorescence' => 'None',
    'CaratPerPrice' => 5282.48,
    'CertificateNumber' => 2131048944,
);

$smarty->assign('details_href', 'array.php?' . http_build_query($diamond));

?>
```

Template:

```
<a class="view_details cboxElement" href="{$details_href}">{$value.ID} View Details</a>
```